# How to convert pipeline().parameters.windowStart to epoch in Azure Data Factory copy pipeline query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I have a timestamp column in DocDb, I would like to query that in Azure Data Factory copy pipeline, which copies DocDb to Azure Data Lake

I would like to

```
select * from c
where c._ts > '@{pipeline().parameters.windowStart}'
```

But I got

```
Errors":["An invalid query has been specified with filters against path(s) that are not range-indexed.
```

In the DocDb policy, I have

```
"includedPaths": [
    {
        "path": "/*",
        "indexes": [
            {
                "kind": "Range",
                "dataType": "Number",
                "precision": -1
            },
            {
                "kind": "Hash",
                "dataType": "String",
                "precision": 3
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
```

I think this should allow _ts int64 to be queried by range.

Where did I go wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduce your issue with your sql and your index policy.

[image]

Based on my observation, it seems that the filter is treated as String,not Int.You could remove the `'` in your sql and try again,it works for me.

sql:

```
select * from c
where c._ts > @{pipeline().parameters.windowStart}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I did tried that early. Error: DocumentDb operation failed: Message: {"errors":[{...,"message":"Syntax error, invalid numeric value token '24T01'."}]}
 ActivityId: 9de19137-66d1-45d3-937f-784556364334, documentdb-dotnet-sdk/2.1.3 Host/64-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0.. Activity ID:9de19137-66d1-45d3-937f-784556364334.
I also tried 
@{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.windowStart, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ' ).TotalSeconds}
@{pipeline().parameters.windowStart.ToUnixTimeSeconds()}
@{pipeline().parameters.windowStart.TotalSeconds}

None seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Jay.

I ended up using [UDF](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2018/01/12/cosmos-db-server-side-programming-with-typescript-part-2-user-defined-functions/)

```
function dateTime2Epoch(dateTimeString){
    return Math.trunc(new Date(dateTimeString).getTime()/1000);
}
```

in Cosmos db.
Then in Azure Data Factory query

```
select * from c 
where c._ts >= udf.dateTime2Epoch('@{pipeline().parameters.windowStart}')
  and c._ts < udf.dateTime2Epoch('@{pipeline().parameters.windowEnd}')
```

However, the query seems to be very slow. I will update this when I found more.

**Update**: Ended up with copying the whole thing.